# What alternatives exist for Autologout in D7

Tags: 7, users

Since the [autologout](http://drupal.org/project/autologout) module isn't ready for prime time for D7, what are some alternatives out there?

Is there any snippet out there already that can be used in a sample custom module that will logout users for x minutes of inactivity?

**Update 1**: 
The [suggested snippet here](http://drupal.org/node/1034288#comment-4484486) keeps D7 from crashing, but does not logout the user.

Thanks!

Comment: In general should be no alternative based on the fact that there shouldn't be duplicated of modules. There might be modules which overlap it's features.... So the real goal of this issue: Port the module, and if you look into the issue queue there is some work going on already. Perhaps you could help or support someone in doing it.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. What you are saying makes sense. I guess what I am looking for are alternatives to the functionality of the module itself -- an SQL query perhaps ... against the sessions table (or other tables ... )? Or as @Nigel suggested below, a cookie timeout. WDYT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up working with a third party, and they helped with getting the version for D7 to work. Look at [#19 comment in the issue queu](http://drupal.org/node/1034288#comment-5193722).

Answer (score 1):

You can just lower the cookie lifetime in your `settings.php` file as a temporary solution.

> Set session cookie lifetime (in seconds), i.e. the time from the session is created to the cookie expires, i.e. when the browser is expected to discard the cookie. The value 0 means "until the browser is closed.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 2000000);
```