# Session Timeout after certain period of inactivity

Tags: 7, users, sessions

How can I logout users after a certain period of inactivity (say 20 minutes)?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [Automated Logout](https://drupal.org/project/autologout) module.

> This module provides a site administrator the ability to log users out
>   after a specified time of inactivity. It is highly customizable and
>   includes "site policies" by role to enforce logout.

Features

- Different timeouts based on role
- Disabling of timeouts based on role
- Permission for users to set their own timeout
- Includes some JS mechanisms to keep uses logged in even if multiple tabs are open or if the user is working on a form for a long period of time.
- Includes developer hooks to allow users to remain logged in depending on your own project specific requirements
- Optional integration with Javascript Timer

(or) take a look at [Session Limit](https://drupal.org/project/session_limit)

(or)

**[Ejector Seat](https://drupal.org/project/ejectorseat)**

> A Drupal module to immediately log out (eject) a user whose session
>   has ended

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, i specified timeout value in seconds as 2 min (120seconds). The session is not getting expired after the specified time.how do i proceed

Comment: Which module your talking about among the 3 I specified, If it not working then it is probably a bug, better you submit to the module issue queue.

Comment: i have used Automated Logout module. but it the session not getting expired after the specified time.

Comment: can't we use any custom code to do the session logout after some period of inactivity?

Comment: @user24393 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186115/drupal-timeout-how-to-amend-timeout-length

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `session.cookie_lifetime` time (in seconds) from the session is created to the cookie expires (when the browser is expected to discard the cookie).

There is a module [Session expire](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_expire) which enhances that functionality.

Related:

- [How to force users to logout after X minutes of inactivity using Rules, Views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/11800/1908)
- [What alternatives exist for Autologout in D7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/8628/1908)